# Only use MD_CARD from Material Design 2 without using all the Material Design library

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-material2

Is there anyway to just use needed material design components and not all the library, I'm interested in MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES.

Answer (score 1):

`MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES` were removed starting with [`Material 2 alpha 7`](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha.7)

Perhaps you could create [a demo project](http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=info) that includes `MdCard` and copy the template and CSS rules from browser dev tools

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the latest release (alpha.9 as of today), what I tend to do is exactly what the [`MaterialModule` does](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/module.ts), but strip it down to what I only need. Something like

```
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

const MATERIAL_MODULES = [
  MdCardModule,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdCardModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES
})
export class MaterialRootModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: MATERIAL_MODULES,
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES
})
export class MaterialModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MaterialRootModule
    };
  }
}
```

Then in your app module

```
imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot() ]
```

and in feature modules

```
imports: [ MaterialModule ]
```

If you only plan on using the `MdCardModule`, then really you can just import that. But I like keeping it the way above so that if I ever need anything else, I just add it to the above module